# Intellij Keep on hanging in Vagrant

Tags: docker, scala, intellij-idea, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I am new to this running Linux using VM. I have configured VM using vagrant to run Linux.

```
System config: 11 Gen i7
RAM: 32GB
VM version: 6.1.34
VboxGuestAddtion: 6.1.34
```

Allocated 16GB and 6 core for VM

Intellij Idea Config, given 4gb to it plus VM options Intellij idea

```
-Drecreate.x11.input.method=true
-Dawt.ime.disabled=true
```

I ran the Gradle project in IntelliJ using Scala, we run services using docker.

After trying many suggestions in StackOverflow and another forum, My system hangs when using VM. Intellij keeps on changing continuously. Sometimes, the mouse cannot click on different tabs in VM, outside it works everything is fine.

Please help in fixing the issue as it is killing my productivity. I need to multiple restarts in a day when it freezes completely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your issues, but if you plan to use Linux for long term, why not install a Linux distribution on your laptop. You can even use dual boot alongside Windows using the GRUB Boot Loader to load the system you want at startup.

Comment: Actually, In our organization, one part of the project uses c# which develops code in windows and docker is not supported in windows. That's why that is not possible to switch completely.

The issue is VM hangs, IntelliJ keeps on freezing so it increased development time. I have increased Ram from 16 -> 32 but still the same.

Comment: Have you checked logs ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors/warnings?